# How to return a sql query into a neatly formatted table

Tags: php, sqlite

I have writen a php file to query a database (SQLite). I have managed to get a bunch of related query however i could not get them formatted nicely into a table. Does anyone know how this could be done ?

CHeers

**I have fixed the existing code. The current output is now in a nice green table**

```
      include_once("/var/www/dBug.php");
         new dBug($myVariable); 
        $result = $db->query('SELECT mac,lat,lon FROM TABLE WHERE ssid = "ssid"');

    $row = array();
    $i=0;

    while($res = $result->fetchArray()){ 

                 if(!isset($res['mac'])) continue; 

                  $row[$i]["mac"] = $res['mac']; 
                  $row[$i]["lat"] = $res['lat']; 
                  $row[$i]["lon"] = $res['lon']; 

                  $i++; 



                  } 
         echo '<pre>';
         new dBug($row)
```

**My Current output**

```
    array(18) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["mac"]=>
        string(17) "00:60:64:af:b9:be"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(-27.5759707)
        ["lon"]=>
        float(153.0646822)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["mac"]=>
        string(17) "00:60:64:af:b9:be"
        ["lat"]=>
        float(114.29077148438)
        ["lon"]=>
        float(30.566990873153)
      }
```

Comment: "Table" is a bit ambiguous.  Are you looking for an HTML table?

Comment: try var_dump($row). Is this what you want?

Comment: var_dump would actually gives me similar output. @darshandzen

Comment: A Html table will do just fine too. I was putting them into table as that would be alot readable @DanGoodspeed

Comment: For one thing, this line is backwards `$result = $db->query('SELECT mac,lat,lon FROM TABLE WHERE ssid = "ssid"');` with the quotes. Try `$result = $db->query("SELECT mac,lat,lon FROM TABLE WHERE ssid = 'ssid'");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried what you suggested. It will bring everything. Apparently what i did was right

Comment: @YeoTzeTian Well, if it works then that's the important thing. I thought it was the problem. Glad it worked out, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You have 2 options to see array elements in proper format.

```
1. Use var_dump() function.

<?php
       var_dump($array);
?>

2. Use print_r() function.

<?php
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($array); 
?>
```

--

Thank you.

Comment: hi @Anandsolanki, would you say my current output is already in a proper format since i have did the print_r method ?

Comment: No You need to use pre tag of HTML to show it in format. Read my answer properly and follow it ................

Comment: My bad. I was under the impression what i had then was the best i could do. I have combined both your solution with @darshandzend 's solution. It is looking pretty awesome now

Answer (score 1):

[`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php);

If you are looking for something fancier, http://dbug.ospinto.com/

Also http://krumo.kaloyan.info/

Comment: Sounds exactly what i need. Cheers

Comment: Was it var_dump() or [ dbug or krumo ] that you needed?

Comment: [link](dbug.ospinto.com) download link is broken, krumo seems promising but i have yet gotten it to work for me.

Comment: Their download url isn't in a good format. Here's one that works: http://dbug.ospinto.com/dl/dBug.zip